# Release Management Continues Release on Error

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm using Release Management 2015 along with a vNext release template. It appears that event when components are placed in a single Sequence control flow container, a failure in a component deployment does not stop the deployment. Instead, the deployment continues to all remaining components and, eventually, the release is marked as a failure.

This appears to be different than Agent-based templates, where the failure of a component causes the immediately failure of the release and the halt in execution of the template.

Is the by design? If so, is there a way to ensure that a release does not continue should a particular component fail?

Some additional details:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1a661e6-90ea-415e-b12c-b0d1ec7a5326/release-management-continues-release-on-error?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Does this happen for any/all components, or just some specific ones that you are using?  Meaning, when a simple, out-of-the-box components fails, does it cause the deployment to continue?

Comment: All components. In this case, as we're using the vNext template, we're using the "Deploy Using PS/DSC" action and pointing those at various configured components. So it's always the same action, but if any component using that action fails, it continues on regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the Sequence container?
I think you'll get the desired behavior if you just drag your **Deploy using PS/DSC** action onto the canvas/root activity (and not inside a sequence container).

In the vNext flow Sequence control is helpful when you have a parallel container and you want to deploy things parallely to multiple machines, and want the sequence of actions to run on each of them. You can safely remove the sequence control and get the desired behavior if you are not doing a parallel deployment.

Meanwhile I'll have a look at my setup and see how the behavior for sequence is.

Comment: I believe this fixed the issue. Very confusing. Thanks for the help!